# Read bytes from NetworkStream (Hangs)

Tags: c#, sockets, networkstream

I'm trying to learn the basics of networking and I've built an echo server from [this](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/win/misc/sockets.html) tutorial. I checked the server with telnet and it works perfect.

Now when I'm using some of the many client samples on the Internet:

```
// Create a TcpClient.
// Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
// connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
// combination.
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

// Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

// Get a client stream for reading and writing.
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

// Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);

// Receive the TcpServer.response.

// Buffer to store the response bytes.
data = new Byte[256];

// String to store the response ASCII representation.
String responseData = String.Empty;

// Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

// Close everything.
stream.Close();
client.Close();
```

It doesn't work very well. If I will comment the stream.Read line, everything works perfect (expect I can't read).  I was also trying to accomplish that in a similar way using asynchronous callback method for the read. and then it only works after I terminate the program (the server handles the request)

I suspect that the way I'm reading from the stream cause this block, but I'm too clueless to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the server is sending you something you could read?

Comment: I can't tell trough debugging, but I saw the data printed back in telnet. I even added "X" to the end of the server's response to be sure that it is the reply from the server.

Comment: How does the echo server read the message? Do you see when the echo server gets the message and replies with your code above?

Comment: You forgot the client.Connect() call.

Comment: No he didn't. The constructor does that.

Comment: @BlueM yes, I've added cout << r;  in the Answer method. and I do see the message being printed. with telenet I can also see the reply.

Comment: Maybe the echo server waits for a line-feed `\n` before it sends back the message?

Comment: @dtb  that's it!   can you post it as answer?

Comment: I supposed this too but you was sure it is your client. Your server has the problem. You didn't show your servers code else we would have solved that in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The implementation will block until at least one byte of data can be
>   read, in the event that no data is available.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx)

Your server propably isn't sending you any data.

**Edit:**

I tested your client and it works perfectly fine. Try it yourself and set the following parameters:

```
  string server = "google.com";
  int port = 80;
  string message = "GET /\n";
```

It's definitely your server which has the problem.

Comment: It is an echo server, It dose returns data and I was able to read the data with telnet. there has to be some problem with the way I'm reading the data because it is there.

Comment: Try flushing what you write. Does the echo server get your message at all?

Comment: Forget about the flushing. MSDN states: "The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams."

Comment: As ffor your suggestion I stream.Flush(); after the write line, it dose not help either.  It dose work for sure if I'm not trying to read from the stream. so I assume it dose gets the data always, it just can't process something as long as I'm trying to read.  but then again, with telnet everything works perfect...