# vb- networkstream write only returns first result (need all)

Tags: vb.net

My code looks very similar to this post [Read bytes from NetworkStream (Hangs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431067/read-bytes-from-networkstream-hangs), which I copied below. ( I realize this is c# - I need a vb solution)

```
        // Create a TcpClient. 
        // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer  
        // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port 
        // combination. 

    TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);  

        // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array. 
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);  

        // Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();  

        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer.  
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);  
        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);  

        // Receive the TcpServer.response.  
        // Buffer to store the response bytes. 
data = new Byte[256];  

        // String to store the response ASCII representation. 
        String responseData = String.Empty;  

        // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes. 
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); 
        responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes); 

        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);  

        // Close everything. 
        stream.Close(); client.Close();
```

My issue lies in this:

I have a form that takes user input on which tif file(s) to find (which ends up being the getBytes(message) ).  When one does this, it always returns one result - the first tif file that fits the criteria, However, I know in certain instances I should recieve more than one match.

Then I send the results to a picturebox and should be able to scroll through results (which this part works fine)

I've tried a few ways to get multiple results, but maybe I'm missing the obvious? My best guess is using the asyncronous beginread/write.... 
I've attempted using a for loop but I end up getting a bunch of the same tif files as a result...

Could anyone help me (even with a generic direction)? I'm not a pro. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your posted code is C#, but you're asking for VB help?

Comment: But you are just sending and receiving one message.. what did you try? how your code looks?? (the real one)..

Comment: Yeah- the vb is extremely similar.. almost identical.. my buffer is larger though because my files can be big (not fixed length)  I tried to get the files and use forloop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out what the issue was.  the data i was looking for wasn't standardized as so the results were the same data over and over.  I changed what items I was looking for and *tada* it worked. anyway, thanks for the help