# Connecting to a TCP server unable to get response

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I have a TCP client that successfully connects to an external Server and I am sending a request to the server which is received successfully.

However when I try and receive the response it just stalls and never receives it.

```
var message = "Hello World!";
var port = 9999; //Changed for question
var ip = "100.100.100.100"; //Changed for question
var tcpclnt = new TcpClient();

Console.WriteLine("Connecting.....");

await tcpclnt.ConnectAsync(ip, port);

Console.WriteLine("Connected");

Stream stm = tcpclnt.GetStream();

byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

Console.WriteLine("Transmitting {0}", message);
await stm.WriteAsync(ba, 0, ba.Length);

byte[] bb = new byte[100];
var bytesRecieved = await stm.ReadAsync(bb, 0, 100);

var response = new StringBuilder();

foreach (byte t in bb)
      response.Append(Convert.ToChar(t));

Console.WriteLine("Received {0}", response);

tcpclnt.Close();
```

I have the correct port open on my computer and on my router.

Comment: Try using Telnet to see if you can get the result from the server.

Comment: You are ignoring the return value from ReadAsync which tells you how many bytes were received. Fix that and update the code.

Comment: Alternatively you can test if code is otherwize functioning using any alternative tcp server for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431067/read-bytes-from-networkstream-hangs

Comment: @usr I have updated the code. the problem is on that line, the code hangs here and doesn't proceed.

Comment: You'll have to show us the server code as well. What are you trying to communicate with? Also, @usr meant you should *use* the return value of `ReadAsync`, not just store it in a variable and ignore it anyway. Use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bb, 0, bytesReceived)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's many things wrong with your code, but one of the biggies is that the other side has no way of knowing when you're done transmitting.

TCP is a stream-based protocol, not a message-based one. That means that there's no 1:1 mapping between sends on one side, and reads on the other. It's like writing and reading a file stream, not like sending e-mail.

This among other things means that unless you're actually working with streamed data, you'll need some way to distinguish messages in the stream from each other. For example, by adding `\r\n` to each of your strings - but that's something the client and the server have to agree on. You'll have to also show the server code if you want more specific help.

As for the other mistakes:

- You can't igore the return value of `ReadAsync` - it tells you how much data was actually read.
- You can't just wave-away the encoding issues - both sides have to explicitly use an (agreed upon) encoding for writing and reading. In your case, this would mean using `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` instead of `Convert.ToChar`.
- Related to the first point, you can't just call `ReadAsync` once and expect to get the whole message (or even expect to get *exactly* one message). For anything realistic, you'll need a loop, reading data as long as there is some.
- No handling of graceful shutdown. Not important if you're only doing HTTP-style "request -> response", but problematic otherwise.

Comment: I will have a look at this, however I cannot supply server code, it is a third party server which I am only given the login details for.

Comment: @BenSharpe Login details by far aren't enough. What kind of protocol is used for the communication? What server is it?

Comment: The only information I have been supplied is an Ip address, port, username and password.

Comment: @BenSharpe That sounds like it's a web application or a web service. Why would you try communicating with that using `TcpClient`?

Comment: As I have been informed by the provider, that I need to connect using a TCP connection, is there a better way of connecting to it?

Comment: @BenSharpe That really isn't enough information, and it's misleading - TCP has no concept of usernames or passwords. Either you misunderstood what the provider was telling you, or the provider was telling incomplete or nonsensical information. What happens if you use your web browser to open `http://theIpAddress:thePort/`?

Comment: I am aware about the username/password, I am supposed to open a stream and send the message including the username and password as a byte array, then they will say if I am logged in or not, then if logged in I can start to send the other messages. I had tried to open it in my web browser before but it just says cannot load. I have experience in using web services and applications just not a TCP connection.

Comment: @BenSharpe Okay, can you edit your question with as much of what *exactly* the provider told you to do? You might have missed some important bit. For example, sending the username and password as a byte array is still pretty vague - how does the server know what's the username and what's the password, for example?